# Bidirectional enum in TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, enums

I have enum like:

```
enum MyEnum {
   key1 = 'val1'
   key2 = 'val2'
}
```

But I haven't idea how to implement `SomeType` that does next thing:

1. Function:

```
const myFunction = (param: SomeType) => {
   ...
}
```

2. Should support next usages:

```
myFunction(MyEnum.key1) // <- gets also enum 
myFunction('val1') // <- gets also values of enum
myFunction('someOtherValue') // <- Error
```

---

P.S. Or at least if enums keys and values identical to get it keys instead of values

Comment: I suppose `myFunction(MyEnum.key1)` would return `val1`, but what do you expect `myFunction('val1')` to return?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen it's doesn't matter what functions returns I just want to check input params :)

Comment: If keys and values are identical, you could just use `MyEnum | keyof typeof MyEnum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TypeScript 4.1 or later, you can a̶b̶u̶s̶e̶ use a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) to achieve this:

```
enum MyEnum {
   key1 = 'val1',
   key2 = 'val2'
}

const myFunction = (param: MyEnum | `${MyEnum}`) => {
   // ...
}

myFunction(MyEnum.key1); // OK
myFunction('val1'); // OK
myFunction('val3'); // Error
```